# Best way to get the next id number without "identity"

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking, deadlock

I have to insert some records in a table in a legacy database and, since it's used by other ancient systems, changing the table is not a solution.

The problem is that the target table has a int primary key but no identity specification. So I have to find the next available ID and use that:

```
select @id=ISNULL(max(recid)+1,1) from subscriber
```

However, I want to prevent other applications from inserting into the table when I'm doing this so that we don't have any problems. I tried this:

```
begin transaction
    declare @id as int
    select @id=ISNULL(max(recid)+1,1) from subscriber WITH (HOLDLOCK, TABLOCK)
    select @id
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    insert into subscriber (recid) values (@id)
commit transaction
select * from subscriber
```

in two different windows in SQL Management Studio and the one transaction is always killed as a deadlock victim.

I also tried `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` first with the same result...

Any good suggestions to how I can ensure that I get the next id and use that without risking that someone else (or me!) is getting hosed?

Sorry for not mentioning this earlier, but this is a SQL 2000 server so I can't use things like FOR UPDATE and OUTPUT

### **UPDATE**: This is the solution that worked for me:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @id int

    SELECT  @id=recid
    FROM    identities WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
    WHERE table_name = 'subscriber'

    waitfor delay '00:00:06'

    INSERT INTO subscriber (recid) values (@id)

    UPDATE identities SET recid=recid+1 
    WHERE table_name = 'subscriber'

COMMIT transaction

select * from subscriber
```

The WAITFOR is so that I can have multiple connections and start the query several times to provoke concurrency.

Thanks to Quassnoi for the answer and to all you other guys that contributed! Awesome!

Comment: try my code, get the max and insert in one statement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create another table:

```
t_identity (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (id = 1), value INT NOT NULL)
```

with a single row, lock this row, and increment `value` by one each time you need an `IDENTITY`.

To lock, increment, and return the new value in a single statement, use:

```
UPDATE  t_identity
SET     value = value + 1
OUTPUT  INSERTED.value
```

If you don't want to update, just lock, then issue:

```
SELECT  value
FROM    t_identity WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
```

This will lock the table until the end of the transaction.

If you always first lock `t_identity` before messing with `ancient_table`, you will never get a deadlock.

Comment: How would you lock and increment it? Similar to the way listed in the question?

Comment: what about just using a single insert like my answer?

Comment: INSERT will work too, but it will clog the table. Why keeping old identites?

Comment: in my answer, I never create an extra table, I just insert into the actual table using a select max() with an output of the new id

Comment: Yes, in case you have row-level locking on the table, this will work too. However, I'd still prefer another table so you can be more free in setting the original table parameters. +1 for your solution, nevertheless.

Comment: This won't work since there is a legacy program which I have no control over that interacts with this database as well. So I can use the extra table but the other program will not.

Comment: From your post I can conclude that a stored procedure is used for inserts. If it's the case, then you can hide all details (including the extra table) into the procedure. FOR OUTPUT is not mandatory, you can use UPDATE first, then SELECT. UPDATE will lock the table as well.

Comment: on my SQL Server 2005:

SELECT  value
FROM    t_identity
FOR UPDATE

results in:

Msg 1003, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Line 3: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.

Comment: UPDATE is not available in SQL 2000, but the other way worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add another table with an identity column and use this new table and column to select/generate your identity values for the old table.

**Update**: Depending on the frequency of INSERTS (and the number of existing rows ***e***) you could seed your new IDENTITY values at ***e+x*** where ***x*** is sufficiently large. Thhis would avoid conflict with the legacy inserts.  A sad solution, an imperfect one for sure, but something to think about?

Comment: +1 I used to do something similar where I create a table with just one column and one row and lock that table instead of using identity value.  Locking a table with just one row and a column didn't seem to affect other transactions.

Comment: This won't work since there is a legacy program which I have no control over that interacts with this database as well. So I can use the extra table but the other program will not.

Comment: Updated with additional suggestion to avoid conflict with legacy inserts.

Comment: @edg - I have also used the e+x "hack" to get around the same issue.  As you say, it's imperfect, but can fix a problem when nothing else is possible.  Just have to be sure that x is sufficiently large to remove possibility of overlap between the "lower" id values and the "upper" id values.

Comment: Yes it is a hack, but your options sound limited...or are they?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** this is basically the method purposed by @Quassnoi, I just implement it in a loop so you can run it against multiple windows at the same time to see it works great.

set up:

create user's existing table:

```
create table Subscriber
(
recid  int not null primary key
)
```

create new table to keep track of the missing identity, you could add an extra column to keep track of a table if this is needed for multiple tables, but I hve not done that in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE SubscriberIDs
(
SubscriberID int
)
insert into SubscriberIDs values (0) --row must exist first
```

create test script, put this into multiple windows and run them at the same time:

```
declare @idtable table --will hold next ID to use
(
id int
)
declare @x  int
declare @y  int
set @x=0
while @x<5000 --set up loop
begin
    set @x=@x+1
    begin transaction
    --get the next ID to use, lock out other users
    UPDATE SubscriberIDs
        SET SubscriberID= SubscriberID+ 1
        OUTPUT  INSERTED.SubscriberID
        INTO @idtable
    --capture the next id from temp table variable
    select @y=id from @idtable
    --print @y
    --use the next id in the actual table
    insert into subscriber values (@y)

    commit
    --print @x
    waitfor delay '00:00:00.005'
end --while
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT** here is my original attempt, which will eventually get some deadlocks when run in a loop and in multiple windows at the same time. The above method always works.  I tried all combinations of transactions, with(holdlock), and set transaction isolation level serializable, etc.  but could not get it to run as well as the above method.

set up:

```
create table subscriber
(
recid  int not null primary key
)
```

used to capture the id:

```
declare @idtable table
(
id int
)
```

the insert:

```
insert into subscriber
    OUTPUT INSERTED.recid
        recid
    INTO @idtable
    SELECT ISNULL(MAX(recid),0)+1 FROM subscriber
```

list the new id:

```
select * from @idtable
```

list all the ids:

```
select * from subscriber
```

Comment: Will this prevent another program from selecting the max recid in the subscriber table and insert a row with the same ID I'm going to use? I have no control over the other legacy program.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get a deadlock here as the second should just wait for the first to complete.  Your issue is that you are creating a transaction, then adding another lock while in that transaction.

Also, you are getting the ID then using it in two separate statements, whereas you could do it all in one solution:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable
begin transaction
    insert into subscriber (recid) 
       SELECT (select ISNULL(max(recid)+1,1) from subscriber)
commit transaction
select * from subscriber
```

This should ensure that you have only consistency on your inserts.  However, as you specify that legacy applications are also using this table, can you be certain that when they insert new records it won't conflict with this?

Comment: This is basically the same as my first attempt. I tried this in a loop and in multiple windows at the same time, and it always resulted in deadlocks.

Comment: The legacy app is the reason I have this problem. I want to lock the table but not make the other app fail with a deadlock...