# How to get the next ID from DB Table without an IDENTITY or GUID Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a table with `INT` primary key column. I do not want to use `GUID` or `IDENTITY` as primary key.

I wanted to know what is the best possible way to get the next ID without using an `IDENTITY` or `GUID` as primary key column in the table. I do not mind using `GUID` or `IDENTITY` in the table unless it's the primary key column.

I have to find the next available `ID` (i.e get the MAX ID and increment it by 1), and use that:

```
SELECT @id=ISNULL(max(AlbumId)+1,1) FROM Albums
```

However, I want to prevent other applications from inserting into the table when I'm doing this so that we don't have any problems.

NOTE: Kindly do not mark this question as **DUPLICATE** . I have gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751270/best-way-to-get-the-next-id-number-without-identity) and could not understand it properly. Would anyone be kind enough to explain me what is it they are doing? And can I use the same technique?

Comment: For the primary key, why not just use an autoincrement column?

Comment: Re. the linked question: they simply keep a table with the seeds. Read the current number, add 1, that's your new ID.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the other solution you linked to? What precisely do you not understand? Have you copied the code and played around with it to understand what it's doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get the next id number without "identity"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751270/best-way-to-get-the-next-id-number-without-identity) I don't want to seem harsh, but this is still a duplicate, regardless of whether or not you understand the answer. If you can give more details about what you don't understand then someone may help, but please don't be surprised if this is closed anyway.

Comment: @Pondlife I already mentioned in the question that i have gone through that question.

Comment: @Pondlife I am not able to understand what are they doing with a new table??

Comment: @Monodeep: that approach sort of "simulates" the `SEQUENCE` - the other table contains a name and a "current ID for that name" kind of entry, and hands out the "next ID for that name" when asked to do so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQL Server 2000 - 2008 R2, using `INT IDENTITY` is **by far** the **easiest and most reliable** way to do it.

Trying to do this yourself is like reinventing the wheel and carries **a lot of ways** in which it can go wrong - so why bother?? You need to (a) make sure this mechanism is concurrency safe (and just doing `SELECT MAX(ID) + 1` is **NOT** safe!), and you (b) need to make sure your mechanism doesn't become a major **bottleneck** in system performance, either...

What's your problem with using `INT IDENTITY` as your primary key?? Doesn't seem very rational...

For SQL Server **2012** and newer, you could also consider using a `SEQUENCE` (which is basically an `IDENTITY` that's not specifically coupled to a single table)

**Update:** [that other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751270/best-way-to-get-the-next-id-number-without-identity) that you mention in your post is doing basically a "do-it-yourself" simulation of a `SEQUENCE`:

- a table holds pairs of (`sequencename, currentvalue`)
- when you ask for a new value for a given sequence, the new value is determined by using **just** an `UPDATE` statement coupled with the `OUTPUT` clause

Why so complicated? This is the easiest and most efficient way (other than using an `IDENTITY`) to safely handle concurrent requests. The `UPDATE` statement will always **exclusively** lock that one row in the "sequence table" for the sequence you want to get a new `ID` from - thus preventing any other transactions to grab the same `ID` and get duplicated values - and it returns the new `ID` using the `OUTPUT` clause back to the caller.

Comment: Ummm...if i have IDENTITY as Primary Key(pID) in Table 1 and this column is being used in another table Table2. Now , if due to some reason i have to delete a few ID's from Table 1 and re-insert those..i would get new id's and Table2 will still have the Old ID's. I mean i want to be able to delete the id's from the main table i.e Table1 in our case and re-insert the same values again....hope am making sense.

Comment: @Monodeep: and you think you can't do that with an `IDENTITY` column? Check out the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (tablename) ON / OFF` command in SQL Server - this allows you to **explicitly** insert whatever values you want into an `IDENTITY` column - just for cases like this .... [MSDN docs on `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: you mean to say , i would have o turn off IDENTIY_INSERT, make the changes and turn it back ON?

Comment: @Monodeep: no just the other way around: you have to **TURN ON** `IDENTITY_INSERT`, insert your explicit values, and then **TURN OFF** `IDENTITY_INSERT` again (so the "normal" IDENTITY processing comes into action again)

Comment: That's great. I owe you a pint. Add it to your list!! and could you please explain me in short what are they doing exactly in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751270/best-way-to-get-the-next-id-number-without-identity)  i linked in my question?